# .NET SDK Project Nuget Packaging: Add Tools Folder?

Tags: nuget, .net-core, csproj

The new .NET SDK projects allow generating NuGet packages directly from various targets as part of the build process.

I realize that `content` is no longer allowed, but it looks like `tools` are still a viable option.

My scenario is that I need to distribute additional content after the package is installed - I understand this can't be done via NuGet anymore and that's fine. However, I want to show a Web page that has instructions for downloading and installing the additional assets.

Essentially I'd like to do something similar to what `Newtonsoft.Json` does:

[image]

I know you can use a powershell script to bring up a Web page, but is it possible to get that script into the NuGet package via the project build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package) `Pack` and `PackagePath` item metadata.

Example from [StackExchange.Precompilation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation/blob/2f31c773a90ad22ae24386205445aa7f841946de/StackExchange.Precompilation.Build/StackExchange.Precompilation.Build.csproj#L25):

```
<None Include="*.targets" Pack="true" PackagePath="build" />
<None Include="App.config" Pack="true" PackagePath="tools\$(AssemblyName).exe.config" />
```

Note, however, that install/uninstall powershell scripts [are not executed anymore, since NuGet v3](https://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html#powershell-install-and-uninstall-scripts). The feature has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-3.1#deprecated), and [feature requests](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1020) to add it back have been rejected. If you still want to give it a shot, your .csproj should contain something like this:

```
<None Include="install.ps1" Pack="true" PackagePath="tools" />
```

---

Also noteworthy:

If you only need your assembly outputs in the `tools` folder (instead of `lib`), you can use the [`IsTool` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets#istool).

Comment: So it looks like that works - the tools folder is added along with the powershell script. However it looks like it doesn't actually run unfortunately. Just double checked and JSON.NET also no longer displays their startup page.

Answer (score 1):

m0sa answered the question I asked, but I wanted to add some additional information here on my actual usage scenario, which is displaying a `readme` file of some sort.

It turns out that Nuget supports adding a `readme.txt` file to the root folder of the Nuget package and if it finds that, it will be displayed. Note the file has to be named `readme.txt` - there's no support for other formats AFAIK.

[image]

While it's too bad you can't have a richer display, at least the text file activates links for clicking.

To do this:

[image]

- Add a readme.txt file to the root of your project
- Then Add this to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="readme.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="." />
</ItemGroup>
```

which causes the `readme.txt` file to be displayed when the package is installed as a primary package. Not displayed when the file is a dependency.